# Limits of Incommensurable quantities

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> By taking the unit of measure sufficiently small, however, the ratio of two incommensurable quantities can be expressed as nearly to the true value as may be desired. Thus an approximate value of the ratio can be found which shall differ from the true value by an amount less than any specified amount, however small.

I don't understand this. Can somebody explain it to me simply and probably give some examples as well? This is an excerpt from the book Geometry for the practical man by J.E. Thompson to those of you curious which book it came from.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ancient conundrum going back to the era of classical Greece.

The Greeks first believed that for any two geometric magnitudes there would exist a common unit which would divide evenly into both magnitudes.

So given, for example, the diagonal of a square and its side they thought there would be a tiny unit which would divide a whole number of times (let is say $m$ times) into the diagonal and a whole number of times (let us say $n$ times) into the side. Then if $d$ is the magnitude of the diagonal and $s$ the magnitude of the side, then

$$ d=\frac{m}{n}\times s $$

However it was learned that in the case of the diagonal and side of a square, there was no such common unit. The actual formula is

$$ d=\sqrt{2}\times s $$

and $\sqrt{2}$ is an *irrational* number, meaning it is not equal to the ratio of any two whole numbers $m$ and $n$.

However, they realized that if one made the units sufficiently small one could approximate, in this case, $\sqrt{2}$ or any such irrational magnitude, to approximate the magnitude with a rational number to any degree of precision required.

For example, $\dfrac{239}{169}\approx1.414201183$ whereas $\sqrt{2}\approx1.4142135562$. So the rational number $\dfrac{239}{169}$ is approximately equal to $\sqrt{2}$ to four decimal place precision. So if we divide the side of a square into $169$ equal units, that unit will go approximately, but not exactly, $239$ times into the diagonal of the square giving an approximation of the ratio of the diagonal to the side of the square.